# Primeng Calendar - Not Updating formControlName value

Tags: angular, primeng, ionic4

Selecting a new Calendar value does not update the value in the formControlName

I tried setting the model property to a string, I also tried setting the dataType on the calendar to a string. To set the default value on the calendar from the model, I have to convert the value to a new date. Listening to onBlur also shows the old value, not the new value.

I am using Angular 7, Ionic 4 and PrimeNg 7.1

ngOnInit() {

```
  this.form = new FormGroup({
      dfrDate: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),



<p-calendar  #dfrDateRef dataType="string"  showButtonBar="true" formControlName='dfrDate' [showIcon]="true" ></p-calendar>
```

I expect the form control value to update automatically, like all other form fields. I can get around this by using viewChild on form submission, but that would a pain to do for every date field in this app

Comment: This is actually a bug in PrimeNG, documented on GitHub: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10636. It's still not fixed. P-Calendar does not correctly update the reactive form control if it has updateOn 'blur' strategy.

Answer (score 0):

To check for changes, use the onSelect event, like so:

In view:

```
<p-calendar 
    [(ngModel)]="inputDate"
    (onSelect)="inputDateChanged()">
</p-calendar>
```

In controller:

```
public inputDateChanged(): void {
    // Do something with this.inputDate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the onselect, that does get me the value.  If I use ngModel with my fomrControl, I get this: 
It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7

In the end, if possible I want my form values to update automatically for all field types without adding listeners.  Otherwise I can add a listener to each date field.